# sfdx mdapi --wait parameter not working?

Tags: salesforcedx, mdapi

Followed a module in trailhead and when i got to the part where i was needed to deploy my work using this command

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d mdapioutput -u MyTP -w 10
```

it throws an error. saying:

> ERROR running force:mdapi:deploy:  Specify the number of minutes to wait as a numerical value greater than or equal to -1. You can
>   specify a decimal value if it is greater than 0.

also tried the --wait parameter in `deploy:report -w 10`. still throws the same error. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if -w 9 would work for you.

Maybe the problem, just a guess, is when the minute contains 2 digits.

If -w 9 works, try -w ”10”

Comment: Tried your suggestion but still throws the same error. Wonder why, do you encounter this kind of error? My deployment not getting completed due to this error. It defaults to 0 mins waiting time.

Comment: and i thought the default value was supposed to be -1 which means until it completes. yet it stops deployment coz it says that deployment taking too long and that 0 minute is not enough.

Comment: It works for me. Try to use the command ’sfdx update’ via cmd, maybe you are not using the most updated version of the CLI?

Comment: thanks! Worked after i updated sfdx. thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that